# SQL Not Auto-incrementing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, auto-increment

I have the following SQL I trigger in a C# app.

All works well but the ID table doesn't auto increment. It creates the value of 1 for the first entry then will not allow other inserts due to not being able to create a unquie ID.

Here is the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE of_mapplist_raw (
    id          integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    form_name   varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    form_revi   varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    source_map  varchar(200),
    page_num    varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    fid         varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    fdesc       varchar(200) NOT NULL
)";
```

I'm sure its a schoolboy error at play here.

Comment: As described, you shouldn't even be getting a `1` in the id field.  What is your insert statement?  Even if you change it to include an `identity` column (as per answers here) your insert may also be a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to specify its seed and increment.( plus , i dont think there is `integer` keyword ....)

```
id  [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
```

the first value is the seed

the second one is the delta between increases

<kbd>A Question you might ask :</kbd>

> delta between increases ? why do i need that ? its always 1 ....??

well - yes and no. sometimes you want to leave a gap between rows - so you can later insert rows between... specially if its clustered index by that key....and speed is important... so you can pre-design it to leave gaps.

*p.s. ill be glad to hear other scenarios from watchers.*

Comment: Inserting between incremental records seems like you've given more meaning to the ID other than uniqueness.

Answer (score 2):

You need to mention the Identity.

```
id  int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```